# OLEDBConnection.Refresh Stopping On Task Scheduler Run

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VB script on an application server to open an .xlsm, and run a function which does the following:

1. Open an Excel file with a OLEDB connection
2. Refresh the connection
3. Save and close

When running manually, everything works as designed. However, when running in Task Scheduler as a specific user whether logged in or not (with password and highest priv, also [both folders are on the server](https://superuser.com/questions/579900/why-cant-excel-open-a-file-when-run-from-task-scheduler)).

From my simple logging method, I can tell that it's failing on the "Refresh" step

```
DisplayAlerts = False

wb.Worksheets("DateRanges").Range("B10").Value = "For Loop"
wb.Save
For Each objConnection In wb.Connections
'Get current background-refresh value
    wb.Worksheets("DateRanges").Range("B10").Value = "Set Background"
    wb.Save
    bBackground = objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery

    wb.Worksheets("DateRanges").Range("B10").Value = "Turn Background Off"
    wb.Save
'Temporarily disable background-refresh
    objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False

    wb.Worksheets("DateRanges").Range("B10").Value = "Refresh"
    wb.Save
'Refresh this connection
    objConnection.OLEDBConnection.Refresh

    wb.Worksheets("DateRanges").Range("B10").Value = "Turn Background On"
    wb.Save
'Set background-refresh value back to original value
    objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
Next
```

In the data source settings, I'm using database credentials, and am passing through the UID/PWD through the connection string.

Any help/advice you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

[image: PowerQuery]

[image: OLEDB Settings]

[image: Query Settings]